# Iterating through list items to set decoration values

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to use a for-loop to iterate to each list-item in the HTML code to set their decorations...

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
items.forEach((item, index) => {
  if (index === 2) {
    document.getElementById("players").style.textDecoration = "underline";
  }
})
```

```html
 <section id="players">
      <h1>Players</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>Alice</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Cesar</li>
      </ol>
</section>
```

How do I make each item be underlined, but not the `<h1>Players</h1>` using my javascript code?

Comment: Is there some reason you can't just do this with CSS?

Comment: And, have you tried the code you've shown? It only loops over the `li` elements, so why would it cause the `h1` to be affected?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are selecting the `li` elements but inside the loop you are setting the style on the `#players` element when `index = 2`. Just remove the if condition inside the loop.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');

items.forEach(item => item.style.textDecoration = "underline");
```

```html
<section id="players">
  <h1>Players</h1>
  <ol>
    <li>Alice</li>
    <li>Bob</li>
    <li>Cesar</li>
  </ol>
</section>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over only the `li` elements but don't test for `index ==2` and set the `style` on the `item` in the loop, not the Heading.

```js
const items = document.querySelectorAll('#players li');
items.forEach((item, index) => {
    item.style.textDecoration = "underline";
})
```

```html
<section id="players">
      <h1>Players</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>Alice</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Cesar</li>
      </ol>
</section>
```

And, of course, you don't need JavaScript for this at all, you can just use CSS:

```css
#players li { text-decoration:underline; }
```

```html
<section id="players">
      <h1>Players</h1>
      <ol>
        <li>Alice</li>
        <li>Bob</li>
        <li>Cesar</li>
      </ol>
</section>
```